# after use RewriteRule dose not open index.php

Tags: php, indexing

after use

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ details.php?brandname=$1
```

in htaccess file for change `test.com/details.php?brandname=abc to test.com/abc`

it does not open directly index.php in directoris

for example `test.com/dir1` it show white page and must type `test.com/dir/index.php` to open

Comment: no. i want use it. but directoris does not open without /index.php

Answer (score 0):

Check this code may be this help you.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]|%20)+)/?$ details.php?brandname=$1
```